# Resource for Blender addons?

Tags: add-on

Trying to keep track of the updates to all the great, user-developed add-ons is fairly frustrating (at least for me). Is there currently a centralized resource where all these amazing add-ons are kept and updated in one location?

If there isn't such a resource, would it be possible to have blender query the collection of installed add-ins and then iterate through on-line references looking at version #'s for add-ins?

Since, as far as I know, it hasn't been done...I have to ask if there are any major flaws in the concept. Of course, in my dream scenario, there would be a "voting" front-end that would allow users to see what the most popular and useful add-ons are and where you don't have to read pages (and pages) of threads.

Comment: There *is* such a 'store'.. it's called the wiki.. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts. Also, this question is a *Feature request* which is very much off-topic. You can refer to the [help page](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for seeing what is off-topic here and before asking future questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resources for Blender](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of online resources available that keep track of a number of Blender Addons, though I am not aware of any one centralized site that covers all of them.

- Your first go-to resource is going to be the [Blender Wiki's *Scripts* page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts), which keeps up-to-date information on all of the addons that come packaged with the Blender installation, as well as several others.
- Another valuable resource is the unofficial [Blender Addon List](http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.com), a listing of many Blender addons maintained by Daniel Banasik.
- Yet another resource is Graphicall.org. I am aware of a number of different user compilations of various scripts, but perhaps the largest of these is [on this page](http://www.graphicall.org/950).

The short answer to your question is that these resources are scattered everywhere, and while there are some that cover a large number of Blender addons, there isn't yet one location that keeps track of all of them.

Furthermore, the process of pulling these resources into one centralized location would be a logistical nightmare, with whole hosts of differences between how different scripts handle updates, as well as certain scripts being made obsolete by updates to new versions of Blender. I won't say it can't be done, but it would certainly be difficult to keep track of those things any better than the resources already out there.

**Edit**: zeffii also pointed out that you can get a zip with the most recent version of Blender and all user-contributed addons at [builder.blender.org](http://builder.blender.org/download/)

**Update**: Added the Blender Addon List and removed a link to an inactive resource.